# AWS ElasticBeanstalk platform updates fails AmazonCloudFormation AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

In a custom VPC with both private and public subnets i've deployed my PHP App (with dev and prod env) using ElasticBeanstalk. It uses a shared ALB that has two listener rules (on port 443 https) based on host, one for DEV that forwards requests to the dev environment of the same application, and one for PROD that forwards requests to the prod env of the application.
It works and now i have to upgrade my Platform (the same problem happens on both envs)

[image: PHP Platform]

The problem is that when it runs, i have this ERROR

> Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-pppqkshxp2-immutable-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition].

Googling i've found that it might depends on EC2 instances that cannot communicate with the EB services but either private and public subnets have internet connection. The private through a Nat GW and the public with an Internet GW. I've tried to `curl www.google.com` from an instance of both subnets and i got the response.

So any idea?

Comment: you need to check the CloudFormation stack that have the error message, and find out the full error information in there. fix that issue and try again

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan under Stack/stackId/Events there's only 
`2022-03-10 09:52:04 UTC+0100 kawlxr CREATE_FAILED Resource creation cancelled`